# Добавить в пин на карту в YandexMapKit 3.1

Tags: ios, swift, yandexmapkit

Каким образом можно добавить пин (с кастомным изображением и обработчиком тапа) на карту используя YandexMapKit 3.1?

Comment: Вот тут (https://habr.com/post/427611/) очень подробно все описано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример добавления пина и регистрация тапа на нем:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: YMKMapView!

...


func configure() {
    let mapObjects = mapView.mapWindow.map.mapObjects

    // покажем пин

    let point = YMKPoint(latitude: 51.532147, longitude: 46.612396)
    let placemark = mapObjects.addPlacemark(with: point)
    placemark.opacity = 1
    placemark.isDraggable = false
    placemark.setIconWith(UIImage(named:"pinImage")!)

    // подпишемся на тапы по коллаутам - см. onMapObjectTap(with:point:)
    mapObjects.addTapListener(with: self)
}

...


// MARK: - <YMKMapInputListener>

extension MapViewController: YMKMapObjectTapListener {

    func onMapObjectTap(with mapObject: YMKMapObject, point: YMKPoint) -> Bool {

        // обработка тапа

        return true
    }

}
```

[Документация по Яндекс.MapKit](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/versions-docpage/)

Полезная [хабра-статья](https://habr.com/post/427611/) на тему, т.к. оффициальная документация на данный момент откровенно скудна и скупа на детали